# get variable from url in javascript

Tags: javascript

`http://localhost/fpo2/approve_beneficiary_approve_form.php?ben_id=1`

here is the code:

```
$("#submitbut").click(function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
    //  alert("hi");
    var ben_id =  <?php $_GET['ben_id']; ?>
    alert(ben_id);
});
```

i want to get ben_id through the javascript code, I don't know how to do this, i am trying to use php code with it , but it is showing undefined.

Comment: Note that if you want to do this in JS, that makes this is a 100% JS question, not a PHP question.

Comment: Try `<?php echo $_GET['ben_id']; ?>;` This way you actually output the value of the argument in PHP. But as the other comments indicated you can get the argument in pure Javascript as well.

Comment: Is this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/get-the-values-from-the-get-parameters-javascript

Comment: Sorry sir, but this code is not working. nothing is showing

Comment: Please be clear in your comments: What code are you referring to, and what causes you to say: _"is not working"_? You used clear language in your question: _"it is showing undefined"_.